# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

Tags: php

These are three files

```
Database.php
Admin.php
```

I got an error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null".
This piece of code runs on my localhost and there is no problem, but when it is uploaded to the server, I have this problem. I use php 8 and xammp software on local.
i am a junior.Please Help Me.

file Database.php:

```
class Database{

private $dbhost = 'localhost';
private $dbname = 'pubg';
private $dbuser = 'root';
private $dbpass = '';
protected $connect;


public function __construct()
{
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    ];
    try {
        $this->connect = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->dbhost.';dbname='.$this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $options);

    }catch (Exception $err){
        echo $err->getMessage();
    }

}

// select
public function select($sql, $value = [], $fetch = 'fetch')
{
    $result = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($value as $key => $item){
        $result->bindValue($key + 1, $item);
    }
    $result->execute();
    if($fetch == 'fetch'){
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $row;
    }else{
        $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $row;
    }
}
```

}

file Admin.php

```
require_once 'Database.php';
class Admin extends Database{
public function checkHasAdmin($chat_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_admin WHERE chat_id = ?";
    return $this->select($sql,[$chat_id]);
}
public function Admin()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_admin";
    return $this->select($sql,[]);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->connect` is null because you need to instanciate your class.

The `__construct()` method is never use.

like that :

```
public function checkHasAdmin($chat_id)
{
    $db = new Database();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_admin WHERE chat_id = ?";
    return $db->select($sql,[$chat_id]);
}
```

Comment: `Admin` extends `Database`, so that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `class Admin extends Database` is pretty clear. So you're instantiating a `Database` class within a class that extends `Database`. It doesn't look right at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have the pdo_mysql extension enabled on the server. You need to locate the php.ini file, and there remove the ';' semicolon from line where it says `;extension=pdo_mysql`. This file should be located in the php installation directory.

It should look something like this:

```
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Edit: I noticed, you didn't call the parent constructor in the Admin class, like @Jeto said

Answer (score 0):

In PHP < 8, giving a method the same name as the class is considered a constructor (even though it has been deprecated for a long time and triggers a Warning).

So when you instantiate your `Admin` class in PHP < 8, it will call `Admin::__construct`, which doesn't call the parent constructor (there is no `parent::__construct`), therefore it will attempt to execute `$this->select` without ever initializing the object (and its `$connect` property), hence the error you're getting.

In PHP 8 however, which you're running locally, this style of constructor has been removed completely, therefore it's a normal method and won't be called when you instantiate an `Admin` object.

[Here's a little demo](https://3v4l.org/r6J6d) which showcases the difference. Note that in PHP 8, nothing gets printed, while in previous versions, "hello" appears.

**Solution**: rename your `Admin` method to something else.